# Зацикливается консольный ввод с клавиатуры на python

Tags: python

Казалось бы, все работает, но в случае, когда пользователь должен заполнить последнее оставшееся поле, ввод зацикливается. С чем это может быть связано, товарищи?

```
import random

def show_board(board):
    print(board[1], '|', board[2], '|', board[3])
    print(board[4], '|', board[5], '|', board[6])
    print(board[7], '|', board[8], '|', board[9])

def check_win(board, mark):
    if board[1] == board[2] == board[3] == mark or \
    board[4] == board[5] == board[6] == mark or \
    board[7] == board[8] == board[9] == mark:
        return True
    elif board[1] == board[4] == board[7] == mark or \
    board[2] == board[5] == board[8] == mark or \
    board[3] == board[6] == board[9] == mark:
        return True
    elif board[1] == board[5] == board[9] == mark or \
    board[3] == board[5] == board[7] == mark:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def new_game():
    global game_on, board
    new_game = input('Хотите сыграть еще? (y/n) ')
    if new_game.lower() != 'n':
        board = list('#' + '_' * 9)
    else:
        game_on = False

def full_board(board):
    if '_' not in board:
        return True
    return False

def check_position(board, position):
    return board[position] == '_'

def enter_player(board):
    position = 0
    while position not in range(1, 10) or not check_position(board, position):
        position = int(input('Укажите позицию от 1 до 9: '))
    return position

def get_computer_position(board):
    position = 0
    while position not in range(1, 10) or not check_position(board, position):
        position = random.randint(1, 10)
    return position

def set_position(board, position, mark):
    board[position] = mark

print('\n' * 100)
print('Крестики-нолики')
board = list('#' + '_' * 9)
show_board(board)
game_on = True
while game_on:
    player_position = enter_player(board)
    set_position(board, player_position, 'x')
    computer_position = get_computer_position(board)
    set_position(board, computer_position, 'o')
    print('\n' * 100)
    show_board(board)
    if check_win(board, 'x'):
        print('Поздравляю, вы выиграли!')
        new_game()
    elif check_win(board, '0'):
        print('Вы програли...')
        new_game()
    elif full_board(board):
        print('Ничья!')
        new_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

потому что у вас 3x3=9 полей

компьютер сделал 4 хода, вы - 5 ходов и дальше опять компьютер делает ход

но поскольку все ячейки поля заполнены, а проверки на это у вас нет, то компьютер все пытается выполнить

```
while position not in range(1, 10) or not check_position(board, position):
    position = random.randint(1, 10)
```

`check_position` не проходит ибо пустых полей нет :)

**P.S.**

ранее я вам писал - соберите все доступные поля и ищите среди них (ну и проверьте на то, что полей не осталось)

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое